# Eigenvectors of the new constructed "blockmatrix"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose one has a symmetric matrix A with some known eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors:

$A= \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1p} \\
a_{21} & \ddots&  & a_{2p} \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{p1} & ... & ... & a_{pp}
\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, I want to consider a new matrix $\hat{A}$:

$\hat{A}= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & a_{22} & \dots  & a_{2p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & a_{p2} & ... & a_{pp}
\end{pmatrix}$.

Is there any relation between the eigenvectors of A and $\hat{A}$?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, [Cauchy's interlacing theorem](http://matrix.skku.ac.kr/Series-E/Monthly-E.pdf) applies

Comment: But there is no information about the eigenvectors?